# Ajax image upload from html file to codeigniter controller - blank $_FILES array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a html file with an image upload form

```
<form name="logo_photo" id="logo_image_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
        <input type="file" id="logo_upload" name="uploadfile"/>
</form>
```

and a jquery script to attemp ajax upload of this form - like this

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $("#logo_upload").on('change',  function(event){            
        $("#logo_image_form").submit();         
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    $("#logo_image_form").on('submit', function(event){

            event.preventDefault()
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: serverUrl+"uploadController/imageuploadAction",
            data:$(this).serialize(),
            cache:false,
            success:function(data){
                console.log("success");
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(data){
                console.log("error");
                console.log(data);
            }
        });




        return false;
                event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

and the controller in the codeigniter framework, simply has a small test return, like this -

```
function imageuploadAction() {
    //testing controller

    print_r($_FILES);
}
```

but the return is an empty array. i want to be writing more code to check and upload the image, like performing tests on `$_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name']` but $_FILES seems to be empty.

What am i missing on this? Any help will be appreciated, Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

File upload is not possible through $.ajax. You can use Iframe or xmlhttprequest version 2 to do that.

The best jquery plugin I've see ever for uploading files through ajax is jquery.form.js. This works in all browsers and uses xmlhttprequest 1.

You can use it in a very efficient way.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, trying out xmlhttprequest now. Btw, what is the differences of using iframe of xmlhttprequest? like, any old browser issues!!?

Comment: Updated the answer again.

Comment: In Iframe you have to make a form virtually and then pass your original form data to virtual form and submit it to internally.

Comment: Not true at all.  You can upload using $.ajax.

Comment: @RayNicholus could you please explain how?? Actually i did not find anything related to it.

Comment: Use the search box at the top of this page for more info.

Answer (score 1):

In general you will be not permitted to get the information about files in $_FILES Array.

But you can do it using a simple script

please follow the below pattern :

```
 $.ajax({
         url: url,  
         type: 'POST',
         dataType: 'json',
         xhr: function() {  // Custom XMLHttpRequest
              var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
              if(myXhr.upload){ // Check if upload property exists
              //if you want you can add any progressbar event trigger here      
              }
              return myXhr;
         },
         //Ajax events
         success: function (data) {

         },
         data: formData,
         //Options to tell jQuery not to process data or worry about content-type.
     cache: false,
     contentType: false,
     processData: false
     });
```

I think you can now get all the required data in your $_FILES global variable.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you include another form field like a redundant hidden text Input to your form and try it again

```
<form name="logo_photo" id="logo_image_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" 
action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="name" hidden />
    <input type="file" id="logo_upload" name="uploadfile"/>
 </form>
```

It looks funny, but try it and see!